# Opening default applications for select files (MSWord, Adobe, etc)

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, ms-word

I need to make an C# app that will enable the user to navigate through (opening and closing) a file list (doc, msg, pdf, etc).

The app needs to open the file in its default application (e.g. Microsoft Word).

On closing, if the file has been edited the default file application will prompt the user to save before closing.

I have seen the [following SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712955/word-interop-how-to-close-one-word-window-without-closing-all-of-them) post, however it's not quite what I'm after:

Comment: Your title says ASP.Net, but that's not in your question.  Is this a web app?

Comment: Apologies, it's actually a WPF application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) Method and [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.100).aspx) Method.