# How to force quit Word using C# Interop

Tags: c#, process, ms-word, office-interop, quit

How can I guarantee the MS Word process exits (using C# Interop library)?

My current approach:

```
// close word document ("doc")
((_Document)doc).Close(SaveChanges: WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
if (doc != null)
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    doc = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

// close word application ("word")
((_Application)word).Quit(false);
if (word != null)
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(word);
    word = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

// and here is how it fails
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
Assert.IsTrue(pname.Length == 0);
```

Sources:

[c# MSOffice Interop Word will not kill winword.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070124/c-sharp-msoffice-interop-word-will-not-kill-winword-exe)

[Disposing of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777422/disposing-of-microsoft-office-interop-word-application)

[Microsoft.Interop object won't quit or "release"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541187/microsoft-interop-object-wont-quit-or-release)

[Excel interop COM doesn't close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497250/excel-interop-com-doesnt-close)

[Ambiguity in Word Interop code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946073/ambiguity-in-word-interop-code)

Comment: Double check that you aren't breaking the two-dot rule, and that you're disposing every office object you create like the ones in your example. I also wouldn't be surprised if you're still seeing the process simply because you check for it immediately after your cleanup code.

Comment: yup, it was all timing - I now realize you gotta wait a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use ReleaseComObject if you use the GC methods for swiping the heap. Also be aware, you need to call the GC methods twice:

```
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Anyway, I always recommend using [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Office (Word) object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article. It is related to Outlook, but the same rules can be applied to any Office aplication (including Word).

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me in any case

```
Word.Application app = null;
Word.Document doc = null;
Word.Tables tables = null;
Word.ContentControls mainControls = null;

try
{
    app = new Word.Application();
    app.ScreenUpdating = false;
    app.Visible = false;
    app.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
    doc = app.Documents.Open(fileName);
    tables = doc.Tables;
        //.. my code 
        if (tables.Count < 1)
        val = mainControls[2].Range.Text ?? "";
        //end of my code
    }
catch (Exception exc) { G.log(exc); }
finally
{
    //CLEAN UP
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); 
    if (mainControls != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mainControls);
    if (tables != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(tables);
    if (doc != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
    app.Quit();
    if (app != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
}
```